# Editing mmaped file of size greater than 2gb in parallel in C is slowing speeds

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mmap, virtual-memory

I am implementing an encryption algorithm that I have designed in C. The algorithm is able to work in parallel using multiple threads. Without going into detail about the algorithm, the basic flow of the program is that the file to be encrypted is mmaped one gigabyte at a time with `void *fileBytes =  mmap(NULL, loadSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset);`. Then 8 threads are created and the 1 gb chunk is split up into 4096 byte blocks. These blocks are dispersed to the 8 threads and are all independent of each other. They are dispersed by passing an array of pointers to the start of each block to the threads. Then, the transformations are made to the blocks and when all the threads are finished, the memory is munmaped and the next gigabyte (or less if there is less than a gb of the file remaining) is prepared to be sent to the threads for encryption.

The code I am using to create the threads is:

```
for(t = 0; t < threadCount; t++) {
    pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, function, &assignments[t]);
} 
for(t = 0; t < threadCount; t++) {
    pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
}
```

I am noticing that for files under 2 gb, this works extremely fast (1 second approx. for 1 gb) and approximately 250-300% cpu is being used on my 4 core intel machine running linux. However, for files over 2 gb the time greatly increases and the cpu usage decreases to approx. 30-40%. For example, an 8 gb file takes approximately 1m 24s. Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening? I realize that this is a very brief overview of my program so please let me know what other information I can provide.

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

I have tested a simple file modification where the first byte of each page is set to 0. 1 gb takes approximately 0.2 seconds but 8 gb takes approximately 30 seconds. Bellow is the code and fileSimpleEdit is the function that starts it. simpleMod changes the first byte and is to act in place of the encryption.

```
void *simpleMod(void *data) {
    //get assignment info
    //assignments are a struct that hold an array of jobs (which are pointers) and the job count
    assignment *assignmentPtr = data;
    assignment currentAssignment = *assignmentPtr;
    job *jobList = currentAssignment.jobs;
    unsigned long long jobCount = currentAssignment.jobCount;

    //setup tracking vars
    job currentJob;
    union block *chunk;

    //BYTE_COUNT is 4096
    /*
    union block {
        uint_fast64_t longs[LONG_COUNT];
        char bytes[BYTE_COUNT];
    } block;
    */

    //go through jobs one by one and set first byte to 0
    for(unsigned long long j = 0; j < jobCount; j++) {
        currentJob = jobList[j];
        chunk = currentJob.start;
        chunk->bytes[0] = 0;
    }//end for each job

    return NULL;
}

int runFunction(unsigned long long loadSize, unsigned long long offset, int fd, 
        assignment assignments[], pthread_t threads[], void *(*function)(void *)) {
    //get pointer to location in file
    void *fileBytes =  mmap(NULL, loadSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset);
    if(fileBytes == MAP_FAILED) { //check for error
        printf("Could not open file to be encrypted\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // malloc the jobs
    unsigned long long chunkCount = loadSize / BYTE_COUNT;
    unsigned long long chunksPerThread = chunkCount / threadCount;
    unsigned long long remainingChunks = chunkCount - chunksPerThread * threadCount;
    unsigned long long addPerAssignemnt = (remainingChunks + (threadCount - 1)) / threadCount;

    for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        assignments[i].jobCount = chunksPerThread;
        if(remainingChunks == 0) {
             assignments[i].jobCount += remainingChunks;
            remainingChunks = 0;
        } else if(remainingChunks >= addPerAssignemnt) {
            assignments[i].jobCount += addPerAssignemnt;
            remainingChunks -= addPerAssignemnt;
        }
        assignments[i].jobs = malloc(sizeof(job) * assignments[i].jobCount);
    }

    //then assignments need to be filled with jobs
    unsigned int t = 0;
    unsigned long long index = 0; //the job index within assignment;
    
    //assign chunks as jobs to assignments
    for(unsigned long long c = 0; c < chunkCount; c++) { //cycle through dimensions
        //setup new job
        job *newJob = &assignments[t].jobs[index];
        newJob->start = PTR_PLUS_BYTES(fileBytes, c * BYTE_COUNT);
        //update assignment
        if(t == threadCount - 1) {
            t = 0;
            index++;
        } else {
            t++;
        }
    }

    //setup threads for fucntion
    for(t = 0; t < threadCount; t++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, function, &assignments[t]);
    } 
    for(t = 0; t < threadCount; t++) {
        pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    }

    //free the jobs
    for(t = 0; t < threadCount; t++) {
        free(assignments[t].jobs);
    }

    //unmap mem
    munmap(fileBytes, loadSize);

}//end runFunction

int disperseFunction(void *(*function)(void *), pthread_t threads[], 
        assignment assignments[], int fd, unsigned long long fileSize) {

    struct timeval start, end;

    //only load up to certain amount of file at time
    for(unsigned long long lc = 0; lc < fileSize / maxLoad; lc++) {
        runFunction(maxLoad, maxLoad * lc, fd, assignments, threads, function);
    }

    //run remainder
    unsigned long long lastSize = fileSize % maxLoad;
    runFunction(lastSize, fileSize - lastSize, fd, assignments, threads, function);
    
    return 0;
}

int fileSimpleEdit(char *targetFile) {

    //get file size
    int fd = open(targetFile, O_RDWR);                          
    struct stat statBuf;                      
    fstat(fd, &statBuf);    
    unsigned long long originalSize = statBuf.st_size;

    threadCount = 8;
    pthread_t threads[threadCount];
    
    //pad the file
    unsigned short paddingSize = BYTE_COUNT - (originalSize % BYTE_COUNT);
    FILE *unpaddedFile = fopen(targetFile, "a");
    if(unpaddedFile == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file to be encrypted\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //create padding
    uint_fast8_t padding[paddingSize];
    memset(&padding, 1, paddingSize);
    //write padding
    fwrite(&padding, 1, paddingSize, unpaddedFile);
    fclose(unpaddedFile);
    close(fd);

    //open file after its padded
    fd = open(targetFile, O_RDWR);                                               
    fstat(fd, &statBuf);    
    unsigned long long fileSize = statBuf.st_size;

    //next setup assignments array
    assignment assignments[threadCount];

    disperseFunction(simpleMod, threads, assignments, fd, fileSize);
    
    return 0;
} //end fileEncrypt
```

Comment: Test code that does a simple modification of each page, like writing a 0 into the first byte. In addition to illuminating a potential interaction with the decryption code, that will give you a [mre] you can share, since it will remove all the decryption code. Also test alternate patterns, such as having each thread work on contiguous blocks (partition the memory into 8 segments and have each thread work on the blocks in its segment, one at a time) and see what the effect is. Also, have you checked whether the results are correct?

Comment: What are the effects of using one, two, or four threads? What other diagnosis have you done?

Comment: How much memory does your system have? For the files under 2 GiB, is the system caching the entire file in memory?

Comment: Hello Eric, thanks for the quick response! I did some preliminary testing and it seems that accessing the memory in order for each thread might be the answer. I did do a test of changing the first byte of each page to 0 and I edited my original post to include that. I also tried different thread counts and i have 16 gb ram. I will keep experimenting with the in order traversal and post back if I am still having issues. Thanks again!